# generating value between random numbers

Tags: java

This is almost a re-post from an earlier question i had, but i have been struggling to point out where the problem could be, but I can't still manage the error.

I have google around for " generating value between random numbers " and found this post
[How do I generate a random value between two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906081/how-do-i-generate-a-random-value-between-two-numbers)

And it feels like im on the right path but I get still the error

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at test1.testvoid$TestVoidMethod.main(testvoid.java:29)*

as told the error points out my row 29

```
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(lastGuess);
```

Any suggestions fellows?

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
String result = "";

int[] myIntArray = new int[10];
int i = 0;
int lastGuess = 1;
result = checkWhichNumberThisIs(0);

while (!result.equals("Equal")) {
    if (result.equals("Higher")) {
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt((10 - lastGuess + 1)) + lastGuess;

        lastGuess = randomInt;
        result = checkWhichNumberThisIs(randomInt);

        System.out.println(lastGuess + " higher");

    } else if (result.equals("Lower")) {

        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(lastGuess);

        System.out.println(randomInt + " array");
        lastGuess = randomInt;
            if (myIntArray.equals(randomInt)) {
                result = checkWhichNumberThisIs(randomInt);

                System.out.println(lastGuess + " lower");
            }
        }

    myIntArray[i] = lastGuess;
    i++;

}
```

Comment: So I guess `lastGuess >= 11` or `lastGuess <= 0`.

Comment: The error is very clear to me: lastGuess becomes negative.

Comment: Your whole code is broken. You are comparing an array to an integer for a start

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Yes. exactly but i cant for the world understand how to not make it negative :)

Comment: @Dymond start debugging, that's your job, not ours. Also, fix your code(array equals int?!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [random number finder, generates - n must be positive. Sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369734/random-number-finder-generates-n-must-be-positive-sometimes). Sorry. Instead of reposting you should really offer a bounty or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously "homework" or a "learn exercise" so here's a "recipe" for finding the problem and fixing it:

1. Start your IDE and switch to the debugger
2. Set a breakpoint at the first line of the method
3. Start debugging, and when the program hits the break point, single step it and watch how the `lastGuess` changes.
4. Develop a mental picture of what is happening (and why), and compare that with your mental picture of how you *want* the program to do.
5. Think about how to fix it ...

Now we could do this for you ... but >>you<< would next to nothing in the process.